# RGB to CMYK, Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Haskell beginner (and new to programming in general), I am trying to write a code that converts RGB color values to CMYK. I have searched around here for reference, and after that I managed to write this:

```
rgb2cmyk :: Int Int Int -> (Float,Float,Float,Float)
rgb2cmyk r g b = ((w - (r/255))/w, (w - (g/255))/w, (w -(b/255))/w, 1 - w)
             where  w = max (r/255, g/255, b/255)
```

When trying to load the module in GHCi I get the following:

```
‘Int’ is applied to too many type arguments
In the type signature for ‘rgb2cmyk’:
  rgb2cmyk :: Int Int Int -> (Float, Float, Float, Float)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I don't really understand what I did wrong, can anyone provide any guidance? Thanks.

Comment: Note that making the arguments `Int` but the results `Float` gives you a problem that's unrelated to the current error: the numeric types need to be converted; Haskell always requires this to be made explicit. Use [`fromIntegral`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) for this.

Comment: Can you please show me how exactly that is done? do I need to change the signature? I simply added fromIntegral like for example: ((w - (fromIntegral r/255))/w, but that didn't seem to make it work.

Comment: You need to do the conversion before all divisions. I would just first convert all the rgb channels before doing any computations; one way to do that is to match “pre-arguments” `rgb2cmyk r' g' b' = ...` and use `where [r,g,b] = [fromIntegral c/255 | c<-[r',g',b']]` to get `r`, `g` and `b` in floating-point and range-normalise form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haskell functions with multiple arguments work in a somewhat strange (but, after you've gotten used to it, extremely useful) way. `rgb2cmyk r g b = ...` is actually just a short way of writing the [lambda expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) `rgb2cmyk = \r -> \g -> \b -> ...`, i.e. this is actually a *nesting* of three functions, each of which takes only a single argument. Hence the type of this function is really

```
rgb2cmyk :: Int -> (Int -> (Int -> ...))
```

Because this pattern is so common in Haskell, the parsing rules are defined so you can omit those parentheses. The signature you're trying to define is thus actually

```
rgb2cmyk :: Int -> Int -> Int -> (Float,Float,Float,Float)
```

Alternatively, you could also make it

```
rgb2cmyk :: (Int,Int,Int) -> (Float,Float,Float,Float)
rgb2cmyk (r,g,b) = ...
```

In this case, `rgb2cmyk` has only a *single* argument, but that has a compound type. I'd argue that this is actually more sensible for this particular function than three separate arguments for each colour<sup>†</sup>.

But `Int Int Int` is not a compound type of three integers, it means something very different: it interprets the first `Int` as a *type-level function* which is applied to two other `Int`s. That doesn't make sense, `Int` is not a type-level function. This is what that compiler error is telling you.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>In fact, you should probably not use tuples but suitably named record types:</sub>

```
data RGB = RGB {_RChannel, _GChannel, _BChannel :: !Int}
data CMYK = CMYK {_CChannel, _MChannel, _YChannel, _KChannel :: !Float}
```

<sub>Here, the `!` makes the individual channels *strict*: it doesn't really make a lot of sense to evaluate all colour channels individually and is more efficient to do them in one go. If you turn on the `-XUnboxStrictFields` extension, GHC will also compile strict records to a much more memory-efficient structure.</sub>

Comment: I forgot (or, more likely, never realized) you could specify multiple fields with a common type like this.

Comment: Unboxing strict fields is an optimization flag, not a language extension, and it's on by default (if optimizations are enabled) for fields that use only a single word when unboxed.